# How to use Prefer-Html-Meta-Tags: al

Tags: facebook, meta-tags, deep-linking, applinks

I'm trying to implement app links for deep linking into my app from Facebook post. I have added all the meta tags as the documentation describes but it is now working. I believe it is because I need to send Prefer-Html-Meta-Tags: al. This git hub references this too but how do I do this? https://github.com/xamarin/Rivets/blob/master/README.md

Comment: No, you shouldn't have to worry about that. That header is only for scrapers and web crawlers, not for end clients.

Comment: Thanks Ming Li. How come it's referenced in the app links documentation? Also when using app links should we expect the app to open automatically or at least get the alert that user is leaving facebook and opening app or take user to App Store? I'm not sure exactly what I should expect. I get the small button at the top but it's kinda obscure. Thank you!

Comment: It's an optional header that scrapers/crawlers can include to indicate that they're crawling for meta tags, it's not a requirement, and unless you have specific use cases around exposing data to crawlers, you don't need to worry about it. As for Facebook behavior, currently it will open a web view, with UI to go to the app (the button is just one of the treatments being tested).

Comment: Thank you Ming Li. I understand. So yeah I do get the web view but I think it should show the alert if app links are detected so we don't have to rely on the user to notice the obscure button at the top. Anyway that's my opinion. I'm proceeding now with FBWebDialogs because this is so far giving me the best experience for my app. It has been challenging to decide what my design would be and which FB technology to use.